# How to tune the performance of ROCm(llvm) compiler?

Tags: gpu, opencl, llvm, amd-rocm

I modified llvm (roc-1.6.x) a bit to generate a code that can run on AMDGPU pro dirver. It can run but the performance is over 10% slower than AMDGPU's online compiler, for the same opencl code.  I wonder if there is some flags I can set to tune up llvm. If you can give me some examples it will be great.

Comment: Could you please show your modification?

Comment: There is some open source project to follow: https://github.com/zawawawa/GCNminC

Comment: I changed some local id and local size to constant and now llvm code is the same fast as amdgpu